# Python: different methods used

Tags: python

Please assist with the following code. I am really struggling.

Define a class Shoe with two member variables style and price. 
The variable style stores a value ‘A’, ‘B’ or ‘O’ and price stores the original price of the shoe.

Add the following methods:

- The init() method for the class which sets style to an empty string and price to 0.0. p111,-114
- A method named assignValues which will assign values to the member variables of an instance of class Shoe.
- A method named calcDiscountPrice() which will calculate the discounted price and return the discounted price to the main program. The discount is calculated as follows:

  - For style A – 10% on original price
  - For style B – 20% on original price
  - For style O – no discount
- A method named dispValues() which will display the member variables of an instance of Shoe.

Write a program that stores instances of class Shoe in a binary file and processes it. Store at least three instances in the file. The main program should be attempted as follows:

- Create an instance of the class Shoe.
- Ask the user to enter the details (price and style) for an instance.
- Add the instance to the file.
- Present a prompt to the user – “Do you want to continue(y/n)”
- The program should repeatedly ask for details of an instance until the user says no at the prompt.
- Once the user has finished adding instances to the file, read the file and display the contents of the file. For each instance display the discounted price as well.

A sample run:

```
Enter a shoe style('A', 'B' or 'O'):O 
Enter price of the shoe:R299.99 
Enter a shoe style('A', 'B' or 'O'):A 
Enter price of the shoe:R349.50
```

The details of each Shoe instance in the file with the discounted price is as follows:

```
Shoe Instance1 
Shoe style: O 
Price: R299.99 
Discounted price is R299.99 

Shoe Instance2 
Shoe style: A 
Price: R349.50 
Discounted price is R314.55
```

MY CODE:

```
class shoe:
    style=""
    price=0.0
    def _init_(self,style=" ",price=0.0,discountP=0.0):
        self.style=" "
        self.price=0.0
        self.discountP=0.0

def assignValues(self):
            self.style=str(input("Enter a shoe style('A','B' or 'O'): "))
            self.price=float(input("Enter price of the shoe: "))
            while True:
                word=str(input("Do you want to continue? (y/n): "))
                if word=="n":
                    break
                else:
                    self.style=str(input("Enter a shoe style('A', 'B' or 'O'): "))
                    self.price=float(input("Enter the shoe style: "))

def calcDiscountPrice(self):
    if self.style =="A":
                self.discountP=self.price-(self.price*0.1)
    if self.style =="B":
                self.discountP=self.price-(self.price*0.2)
    if self.style =="C":
                self.discountP=self.price

def displayValues(self):
                print("\n\n The details of each shoe instance in the file with discount")
                print("Shoe style: ", self.style)
                print("Price: R", % self.price)
                print("Discounted price is R", self.disountP))

s=shoe()
f=open("ShoeDetails.bin","w")
s.assignValues()
s.calcDiscountPrice()
s.dispValues()
pickle.dump(s, file)
file.write(s)
file.close()
del r
f=open("ShoeDetails.bin","r")
storedobj = pickle.load(f)
print(storedobj.dispValues())
```

Comment: can you narrow down your question to WHAT EXACTLY are you strugling with?

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with the code you wrote. Do you get errors (if it is the case, then add the complete error traceback), or an output different from the expected one (then indicate both of them).

Comment: I get errors and I am not sure why. Error in line 40, in <module>. Pickle.dump(s.file) TypeError. must be str, not bytes

Comment: `_init_` should be `__init__` -> note the *double* underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
f=open("ShoeDetails.bin","w")
```

To

```
f=open("ShoeDetails.bin","wb")
```

Note `w` and `wb`. When writing to a bin file which is in binary mode you need to use the option of `wb` (write binary).

Comment: Please format your answer properly and if applicable add a description to it too. @Frank